# Parsing gcc error log

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I am currently parsing the error log of `gcc` like

```
main.c:5:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
main.c:8:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’
main.c in function 'TryAdddition()'
main.c:24:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
main.c:24:10: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
```

5,8,24,24 are the line numbers where exactly the errors or warning had occurred. 
I need to replace these numbers with numbers+10 *i.e:* `15,18,34,34`.

However not every line is a error or warning line.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was cross-posted here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36949/addition-with-sed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say `awk` is a great tool for this job. To apply the change to only the `error` or `warning` lines:

```
$ awk '$4==" warning" || $4==" error"{$2+=10}1' FS=':' OFS=':' file
main.c:15:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
main.c:18:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘void’
main.c in function 'TryAdddition()'
main.c:34:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
main.c:34:10: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default
```